# Actualizar combobox desde otro UserForm | Vba Excel

Tags: excel, formularios, vba, combobox, listbox

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo el siguiente problema en un proyecto de VBA y agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Tengo un formulario Userform1, dentro cual tengo los siguientes campos.

Fecha

Empleado

Categoria*

Servicio

Precio

Cantidad

Total

De entre estos campos el campo Categoria es un combobox, el cual ayudado de la propiedad del objeto rowsource alimento de la tabla 1 en en Excel

Categoria
Opcion 1
Opcion 2
Opcion 3

Tengo un formulario Userform2 para poder crear categorias, es decir alimentar la tabla 1.

Aqui viene mi problema, cuando abro el Userform1 y se me genera la necesidad de crear una nueva categoria, abro desde el mismo formulario el Userform2 para crearla, mediante un botón con el código Show UserForm2, pero al crear la categoria, se anexa en la tabla, luego cierro el userform2 y estando nuevamente en el Userform1, cuando desplego el combobox Categoria este no se actualiza y no me muestra la nueva opción que he acabado de crear.  Solo cerrando y volviendo a abrir el formulario se ve la nueva opción. Inclusive a veces se me bloquea excel y se cierra por completo.

```
 Private Sub Cancelar_Click() 
    Unload Me End Sub 
 Private Sub CommandButton17_Click() ' botón para mostrar el Form Categorias '
Me.Hide Categorias.Show 
Me.Repaint 
End Sub FORM CATEGORIAS

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
  Unload Me 
End Sub 

Private Sub GuardarCategorias_Click() 
  Dim FILA As Integer FILA = Hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
   If categoria <> Empty Then Hoja1.Cells(FILA, 1) = UCase(categoria) 
    categoria = Empty 
   Else 
   End If 
End Sub –
```

Alguién tiene alguna pista, que me pueda ayudar a solucionarlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo mas facil es que agregues tu codigo para que te ayuden, pero lo que te esta pasando es que te falta un evento que detecte cuando volves al form1 que vuelva a cargar la lista del combo box

Comment: Muchas gracias. El código que tengo. Es simplemente desde un botón del Userform1. Userform2.show

Comment: Sin ver el código es imposible ayudarte mucho. Probablemente estés alimentando el  combobox de tu form1 al abrir el formulario (con el evento Initiate) que sólo actualiza valores al abrirse. Por eso, por muchas categorías que añadas desde el otro formulario no van a aparecer en el form1. Puedes cambiar de evento y que el combobox del form1 se rellene al hacer click en él. Así no es necesario cerrar el form y abrirlo. Pero ya te digo que sin ver tú código es complicado proporcionarte ayuda.

Comment: Hola @dogwall. No se si es posible adjuntar archivos a través de esta red, es algo así lo que tengo:

Comment: Private Sub Cancelar_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub




Private Sub CommandButton17_Click() ' botón para mostrar el Form Categorias

'Me.Hide
Categorias.Show
Me.Repaint
End Sub
FORM CATEGORIASPrivate Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub GuardarCategorias_Click()



Dim FILA As Integer


FILA = Hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If categoria <> Empty Then

Hoja1.Cells(FILA, 1) = UCase(categoria)


categoria = Empty


Else



End If

End Sub

Comment: @dogwall el combobox se alimenta desde las propiedades del botón en rowsource y hago referencia a una tabla.

Comment: Por favor, no añadas el código dentro de un comentario. Edita tu pregunta original, y añade toda la información. Facilita a la comunidad que puedan ayudarte. Cuanto más compliques la lectura de tu propia pregunta, menos ayuda recibirás.

Comment: Deberias realizar el recorrido de la pagina para que te indique como funciona bien el sitio para que puedas aprovecharlo al maximo

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo haré.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que actualizar el ComboBox cada vez que se agregue una nueva categoría.

Esto lo puedes hacer en el mismo procedimiento donde agregas la nueva categoría, pero asumiendo que las categorías también se agregan sin que el Userform1 este abierto, es necesario comprobar si el Userform1 esta visible.

El siguiente código lo puedes poner en la parte final de GuardarCategorias_Click
(también puedes ponerlo en el evento `Terminate` del userform2)

```
If Userform1.Visible = True Then
    Userform1.cboCategoria.RowSource = Range("Categorías").Address
End If
```

Comment: mil gracias. Me funciono perfecto